# X509_NAME - how to get the actual buffer?

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509

I am adding openssl to my application and I can send and receive data however so far it is not encrypted or checking the certificates.

I get the servers certificate with:

```
X509 *gCert = NULL;
X509_NAME *gCertName = NULL;

gCert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(sslConnection.ssl);

gCertName = X509_NAME_new();
gCertName = X509_get_subject_name(gCert);

certNameLen = strlen(gCertName);
memcpy(write_buffer, gCertName, certNameLen);
```

Then I write write_buffer to the SSL socket but what I receive in the other end is just gibberish.

How do I use X509_NAME? strlen does not work on it it seems? I get the length 4 which is the pointer size I think, not the buffer size...
And what encoding is X509_NAME? It does not seem like utf-8...

I know sending downstream works, if I just put 0xAA or 0XBB in the buffer it is received correctly on the other end.

Answer (score 4):

You are fairly close. However X509_get_name returns a X509_NAME structure which you need to cast into a human readable string (or use 'as-is' for detailed and safer comparisons; as parsing/comparing plain ascii is a bit risky - a clever adversary could put things like 'C=' in the actual text).

The easiest of the lot is

```
    X509 * gCertName  =SSL_get_peer_certificate(con);
    // if null - error out
    const char * buf = X509_NAME_oneline(gCertName, 0, 0);
    // if null - release memory and error out
    printf("Client\t: %s\n", buf);
    OpenSSL_free(buf);
    X509_free(gCertName);
```

which nets you a one line approximation as a C \0 terminated string. Note that the _oneline functions are depricated - see the man pages of openssl for more elaborate ways to get a text rendition which is UTF8 and multi-line safe. But above is fine for simple things like pure ASCII westerncharset domain names without things like alternatives/variants.